# DocuSign : DocuSign.eSign.dll after upgrading to 3.1.1.0 stop working for ApiClient.GetUserInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I have integrated docusign 3.0.1 with my c#.net project and its working fine but as we upgrade the docusign to 3.1.1.0 it start giving me the below error.

> {"Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code
>   Completed with response Body:
>   '{\"error\":\"internal_server_error\",\"reference_id\":\"1572c036-9cf1-4d1f-b547-e3433f225c67\"}'"}

it will generate this error at below line of code.

```
 OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = ApiClient.GetUserInfo(authToken.access_token);
```

I'm able to generate the access_token but then it generate the mention error.

I refer the below github repository.

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client

Comment: i have integrated below github sample.
https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It genrate the error when you call "ApiClient.GetUserInfo" because it will set the Live Environment BasePath and i was doing the testing on sandbox environment.

For DocuSign Version 3.1.1.0 i have to set the basePath by executing below mention code.

```
ApiClient.SetOAuthBasePath("https://account-d.docusign.com");
```

We have to set this before call the

```
ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken
```

Note : this steps required only for SandBox Environment.